# Two divs with fluid content floating next to each other. IE 7 Not displaying the correct layout

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

### The Case

I have two floating divs next to each other. Both have "fluid" contents and I want them to stay next to each other unless they touch. Then, I want them to be stacked.

The problem is that my fluid content (like text or a list) crumbles in IE 7 as soon as the two divs touch. On top of that, this only happens with some IE 7 versions, not all.

---

### The Code

```
<div class="left-aligned">
    <p>This is some text of undetermined length.</p>
</div>
<div class="right-aligned">
    <p>This is some text of undetermined length as well.</p>
</div>

.left-aligned {
   float: left;
}

.right-aligned {
   float: right;
}
```

---

### The Test

1. [**Case 1**](http://jsbin.com/ekaze)
2. [**Case 2**](http://jsbin.com/ozixo)

---

### The Problem

So,apparently, this issue **only happens with IE7** and appears to be **random**. Some people see the wrong layout, some the correct one. Anyone who can shed a light?

Comment: Case 3 is not happening for me on IE either? Is it IE6?

Comment: Are you testing your own page or the example I posted? Do you have a proper DOCTYPEs? On IE7, Windows XP for me the Case 2 link looks identical in FF and IE.

Comment: I tested your example. Both IE 6 and 7 on my Windows XP machine fail to display the proper behaviour. This is my IE7: http://yfrog.com/5cie7j

Comment: Tested on 2 computers in my house, this is the proper IE7 behavior: http://www.rootspot.com/stackoverflow/ie7.jpg - Not sure why you're seeing what you're seeing...

Comment: Now I'm getting really desperate. :) I tested it on my Thinkpad and on a friends' machine. Both show the wrong layout.

Comment: tested on 3rd computer, showing wrong layout... :?

Comment: I knoow. I tested it on an other computer. Showed the correct layout. So apparently it's random?

Comment: Not random, no. I'm sure there's a common denominator somewhere. I just have to think about it some.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I misunderstood, this is easily done by floating the 1st div to the left and 2nd div to the right.

[Here is an example of Case 1.](http://jsbin.com/ekaze)

[Here is an example of Case 2.](http://jsbin.com/ozixo)

I wrapped them in a `<div>` of fixed width in the example to more easily illustrate the behavior, but without it the same effect would happen just relative to the viewport.

Comment: Your example is exactly what I want to achieve. It appears that this is an IE issue. :(

Comment: To be clear: These examples have now been put into the question. They *should* behave correctly, but don't always. IE 7 seems to be occasionally reluctant.

Answer (score 1):

Add css:

```
.left-aligned {
   float: left;
}

.right-aligned {
   float: right;
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, this should give you exactly the behaviour you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS2 specifications state "A floated box must have an explicit width". See the float section (9.5) in [Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/visuren.html).  If no width is set, the results can be unpredictable.

Comment: Hmm. So, how would you suggest creating the effect I want without explicitly defining a width? The contents are of an undetermined length. There's no way to know. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think there is any way with just css. You may be able to use javascript to monitor the width of the left and right sides and put a width on the right float if left width + (unfloated) right width > 100%